# cqlsh: Inserting a value in UDT

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I have created a UDT -

```
CREATE TYPE home.my_object (
   id text,
   type text,
   quantity int,
   critical boolean,
   count int,
   stock text,
   envelope boolean
  );

 ALTER TABLE home.product ADD my_objects list<frozen<my_object>>;
```

I wrote an script and tried to run against the db to perform insert/update but getting error message

Here is my script-

```
       Update home.product set my_objects[''] = {
         id: '3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN',
         type: 'COMPONENT',
         quantity: null,
         critical: '',
         count: null,
         stock:'',
         envelope:''
     }  where id = 'FIT-GI';
```

When am executing this statement am getting below error-

```
      code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid STRING constant () for "idx(my_objects)" of type int"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataType for critical and envelope is boolean so you have to use value as True/False

If you want to update particular index in list then your query will be:

```
 Update home.product set my_objects[0] = {
         id: '3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN',
         type: 'COMPONENT',
         quantity: null,
         critical: true,
         count: null,
         stock:'',
         envelope:true
     }  where id = 'FIT-GI';
```

**Note:** Replace 0 with your desired index

If you want to add values to the existing list then your query will be:

```
 Update home.product set my_objects = my_objects + [{
         id: '3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN',
         type: 'COMPONENT',
         quantity: null,
         critical: true,
         count: null,
         stock:'',
         envelope:true
     }]  where id = 'FIT-GI';
```

If you want to replace value of my_objects completely then:

```
 Update home.product set my_objects = [{
         id: '3.MYFIT-LTR-DYN',
         type: 'COMPONENT',
         quantity: null,
         critical: true,
         count: null,
         stock:'',
         envelope:true
     }]  where id = 'FIT-GI';
```